# Remove 'duplicate' from full text query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm expanding on default WordPress search with fulltext, and have an SQL query that looks like this

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT wp_posts.*,
  MATCH (wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_content) AGAINST ('"string" @4' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS p_score,
  MATCH (wp_postmeta.meta_value) AGAINST ('"string" @4' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS pm_score
FROM wp_posts
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_icl_translations ON wp_posts.ID = wp_icl_translations.element_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_icl_languages ON wp_icl_translations.language_code = wp_icl_languages.code AND wp_icl_languages.active = 1
WHERE 1=1
  AND IF(
    MATCH (wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_content) AGAINST ('"string" @4' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > MATCH (wp_postmeta.meta_value) AGAINST ('"string" @4' IN BOOLEAN MODE),
    MATCH (wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_content) AGAINST ('"string" @4' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0,
    MATCH (wp_postmeta.meta_value) AGAINST ('"string" @4' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0
  )
  AND wp_icl_translations.language_code = 'hr'
  AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY p_score DESC LIMIT 0, 12
```

The problem is that I have both `p_score` and `pm_score` in the resulting table, so duplicates will happen like

```
ID  | ... | p_score  | pm_score
234 | ... | 9.234234 | 8.234323
234 | ... | 9.234234 | 0
```

While technically they're not duplicates (different scores), I am still seeing duplicates in my search.

Can a query be made such that once I have the results from the `MATCH`, I compare which score (`p_score` or `pm_score`) is higher and then just chose the one with the higher score to show? I tried something like that in the `WHERE` clause, but obviously, I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) MySQL function.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT wp_posts.*,
  GREATEST(
    MATCH (wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_content) AGAINST ('"string" @4' IN BOOLEAN MODE),
    MATCH (wp_postmeta.meta_value) AGAINST ('"string" @4' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  ) as score
FROM wp_posts
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_icl_translations ON wp_posts.ID = wp_icl_translations.element_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_icl_languages ON wp_icl_translations.language_code = wp_icl_languages.code AND wp_icl_languages.active = 1
WHERE 1=1
  AND IF(
    MATCH (wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_content) AGAINST ('"string" @4' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > MATCH (wp_postmeta.meta_value) AGAINST ('"string" @4' IN BOOLEAN MODE),
    MATCH (wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_content) AGAINST ('"string" @4' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0,
    MATCH (wp_postmeta.meta_value) AGAINST ('"string" @4' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0
  )
  AND wp_icl_translations.language_code = 'hr'
  AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY p_score DESC LIMIT 0, 12
```

That should let you pick the greatest of the two and just give them as `score`.

If you want to know if it was a `p_score` or `pm_score`, then you'd likely need to keep getting both scores back and deal with the duplicates and comparisons at the code level.

Comment: This gets rid of duplicates. I'm not really interested from which part the greatest score came from, only the score matters :) Thanks!